# How can I install Docker Desktop on Ubuntu 20.04? (current version requires 22.04 or 21.10)

Tags: 20.04, docker

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and want to test a software on docker. But [Install Docker Desktop on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/)  says I need Ubuntu 22.04 or 21.10. And [Install Docker Engine on Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) says Ubuntu 20.04 is OK. Two questions.

1. What is the difference between `Docker Desktop` and `Docker Engine`? Can I just install Docker Engine and use it?
2. Docker has been around for many years so there should be `Docker Desktop` for Ubuntu 20.04. Where can I find it?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for the Docker Support Site. https://www.docker.com/support/ BTW 21.10 is EOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to address both your questions. Docker Desktop is a relatively new product for Linux, which is why it was first released on 21.10 - so in short, Docker Desktop is not supported on Ubuntu 20.04.

The benefit of Docker Desktop is an integrated application with a GUI where containers can be managed. A somewhat similar solution with a web management interface (called [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/)) exist for Docker Engine.

You can get the exact same functionality from Docker Engine - but this is controlled either by CLI or by a 3rd party app such as Portainer.

If you want to control your containers with a native GUI app (Docker Desktop), you should upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Thanks for the kind explanation!